# using javascript shuffled integers to populate sequential html areas

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, shuffle

I'm trying to change the contents of sequential divs with randomly-ordered contents. It's not working so well.

I have about 25 `<div>` tags that, because of other javascripts regulating touch behaviour, are unable to be put in a randomised order using the usual methods. So instead, I'm trying to have the *contents* of those `<div>`s randomised by setting different `innerHTML` values when the document is loaded.

I have a script that provides random integers as I need, but then I'm having trouble getting it to populate the ordered divs.

Here's what I'm using that isn't working:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(25);
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
  list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);

Object[] randomNumbers = (Object[])list.toArray();

function testit() {
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        var a = document.getElementById('if'+i);
        a.innerHTML = randomNumbers[i];
    }
}
```

What I'd like to see is that this takes all my `<div>`s which have id's such as "if1" "if2" and so one and then set the content of that `<div>` with the randomised numbers.

I know `document.getElementById('if'+i)` is surely the wrong way to get ID "if1" then "if2", but I'm not really sure how else it can be done.

Basically I just need a way to populate 25 absolutely-positions `<div>`s with 25 chunks of HTML content but in a random order. I'd think that could be done by pairing sequential numbers to randomly ordered numbers and tying those into `<div>` id's.  Normally I'd just do this with PHP and be done already but I need it to work as an offline mobile webapp so I'm trying to do it with JS and CSS. I'm definitely open to other approaches.

**edit:** 
If the code above is Java and not Javascript, that's the problem. Then I guess I'm looking for alternative ways, in Javascript, to produce random, non-repeating integers and link those to sequential integers, all between 1 and 25

Comment: The relationship between your JavaScript code and your Java code is not at all clear.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was all javascript and no java code. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Only those two lines towards the end, starting with "var a ...", are JavaScript.  Everything else looks like Java.  In that state, it won't work at all in any environment I know of.

Comment: Can you show what you have so far using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The above is what I'm using so far, plus divs with ID id if1, if2 if3…
If the main part of that code above is Java, that's certainly my problem. Then the question is how to do the same thing w/ javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation using javascript:

```
function shuffle(arr){
    //simple shuffle algorithm - you can also use other
    //we will get simple base index as basis for swapping elements
    //we will swap the array elements arr.length times 

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    for(var i=1;i<arr.length; i++) {            
        var t = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[index];
        arr[index] = t;
    }
    return arr;
}

//create an array
var numbers =[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    numbers.push(i);

//call the shuffle function
//call this many times to reshuffle elements
numbers = shuffle(numbers);
//document.write(numbers.join(','));

//test
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    var a = document.getElementById('if'+i);
    a.innerHTML = numbers[i];
}
```